# Create a tar file from git repository for a specific branch using custom command line option

Tags: bash, git, timestamp

I have just started learning bash and my requirement is.

1. To create a tar file from git repository specific branch ( To be a
   user input ).
2. The tar file should be created with name as current ,
   in /var/tmp/ folder
3. My team wants me to use Command line options
   such -b  -r using while getopts.

I have been breaking the head on this and have come with a script i am sure has lots of error. Request to please correct and clarify the doubts.

```html
#!/bin/bash

# This script is to clone the git repo and create a tar file

GIT_BRANCH=""
GIT_REPO="https://github.com/xyz/abc"

function HELP {
  echo -e "\nUsage: ${BOLD}$SCRIPT [-b <git_branch>] [ -r <git_repository> ] ${NORM}"
  echo -e "\t-b  Git branch to use for testbed creation"
  echo -e "\t-r Git Repository to create tar file"
  echo
  exit 1
}

while getopts b:r FLAG; do
  case $FLAG in

b)
      GIT_BRANCH=$OPTARG
      ;;
\?)  #unrecognized option - show help
      echo -e \\n"Option -${BOLD}$OPTARG${NORM} not recognized."
      HELP
      ;;
  esac
done

VERSION="$(date '+%Y_%m_%d_%H%M')"
mkdir /var/tmp/$VERSION
cd /var/tmp/$VERSION
tar -czvf $VERSION.tar.gz -b $GIT_BRANCH $GIT_REPO
```

Comment: Hint: read `man git-archive`

Comment: This is not a real question. Do some work yourself, and then if you run into an issue ask a real question.

Answer (score 0):

Your tar command would need a `.tarignore` in order to not include the .git folder and its settings.

But that is what [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) does natively

Example: Create a tar archive that contains the contents of the latest commit on the branch '`name`', and extract it in the `/var/tmp/name` directory.

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix=${name} ${name}| (cd /var/tmp/ && tar xf -)
```